# Extract a single file from a list of directories in Linux

Tags: file-copy, search

I have a folder that contains 1208 folder. In each of these folders, I have 6 different files which follows a special naming criteria.

What I need to do is to get only one of these files from all the 1208 folders if it contains the following in its name: _fa_a

The hard way is to go into each of the folders and copy that file to my destination folder.

Is there an easier way to do so? or I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find your_folder -type f -name "*_fa_a*" | while read filename; do echo mv "${filename}" destination_folder; done
```

this find command finds the file and move to the destination_folder.

i added echo command for you to verify the results before move it. once you are happy with echo command output, remove the mv command.

Comment: Why not use `-exec` option of `find` instead of piping to a loop ?

Comment: As in `find ...... -exec echo mv {} destination_folder \;`